# Any good providers of hosted VPN?

Tags: vpn

Does anyone know a good and fairly prices hosted VPN provider? We really don't want to get to the business of hosting our own OpenVPN server for our small network. Tried peer-to-peer ones like Hamachi but they usually have issues in EC2.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?  We're faced with a similar situation: EC2 instances (behind VPC) with multiple sites wanting to connect via VPN. As far as I can tell I can only create one tunnel to one 'customer gateway' from the Amazon VPC side, so I'd like to make that tunnel be to a hosted VPN provider. Then all sites could connect to that provider (including roaming users).

Comment: The only solution we found was to run OpenVPN on a separate EC2 instance.

Comment: Ah ok - thanks Khash.  I also looked at Vyatta (there are AMIs for it up there) but given the complexity we'll probably just end up with a hardware router in colo.

Answer (score 0):

What's the end goal here?  You'll need to have connectivity between your office and the VPN provider if you don't host the VPN your self.

Comment: The end goal is to have a private network between the servers as well as clients connected to them when the servers/clients are on different locations (say EC2, GoGrid and our clients)

Comment: By your clients I'm assuming you are talking about company workers?  Can't you setup EC2 and GoGrid to do a site to site VPN to the office?